# How to append last sql row to a list without replacing previous rows in Golang

Tags: go

This code delivers AFAIK correct JSON output [{},{}], but each row is appended and replaces all previous rows, so the result shows only copies of the last row.

```
var rows *sql.Rows
rows, err = db.Query(query)
cols, _ := rows.Columns()
colnames, _ := rows.Columns()
vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))

for i, _ := range cols {
   vals[i] = &cols[i]
}

m := make(map[string]interface{})
 
for i, val := range vals {
  m[colnames[i]] = val
}
    
list := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
for rows.Next() {
err = rows.Scan(vals...)
   list = append(list, m)
}
json, _ := json.Marshal(list)
fmt.Fprintf(w,"%s\n", json)
```

This is what happens behind the scenes looping through the rows:

> loop 1: {“ID”:“1”,“NAME”: "John }
>
> loop 2: {“ID”:“2”,“NAME”: “Jane Doe”}{“ID”:“2”,“NAME”: “Jane Doe”}
>
> loop 3: {“ID”:“3”,“NAME”: “Donald Duck”}{“ID”:“3”,“NAME”: “Donald Duck”}{“ID”:“3”,“NAME”: “Donald Duck”}

The rows.Scan fetches the correct values, but it appends AND replaces all previous values.

The final output is this

> [{“ID”:“3”,“NAME”: “Donald Duck”},{“ID”:“3”,“NAME”: “Donald Duck”},{“ID”:“3”,“NAME”: “Donald Duck”}]

But should be this:

> [{“ID”:“1”,“NAME”: “John Doe”},{“ID”:“2”,“NAME”: “Jane Doe”},{“ID”:“3”,“NAME”: “Donald Duck”}]

What am I doing wrong?

You may downvote this, but please explain why. I am still a newbie on Golang and want to learn.

Comment: You are appending m to list over and over again without modifying m. Why do you expect the slice elements to be different afterward?

Comment: Oh, I see now. You seem to think that m is copied somehow. That is a) not true and b) wouldn't change anything because the map stores pointers. So copying the map would copy the pointers but they would still all point to the same values. But Scan changes the values pointed to, not the pointers; the addresses don't change. Long story short, `make` a new map for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it and explained with comments what you did wrong:

```
// 1. Query
var rows *sql.Rows
rows, err = db.Query(query)
cols, _ := rows.Columns()

// 2. Iterate
list := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
for rows.Next() {
    vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    for i, _ := range cols {
        // Previously you assigned vals[i] a pointer to a column name cols[i].
        // This meant that everytime you did rows.Scan(vals),
        // rows.Scan would see pointers to cols and modify them
        // Since cols are the same for all rows, they shouldn't be modified.

        // Here we assign a pointer to an empty string to vals[i],
        // so rows.Scan can fill it.
        var s string
        vals[i] = &s

        // This is effectively like saying:
        // var string1, string2 string
        // rows.Scan(&string1, &string2)
        // Except the above only scans two string columns
        // and we allow as many string columns as the query returned us — len(cols).
    }

    err = rows.Scan(vals...)

    // Don't forget to check errors.
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Make a new map before appending it.
    // Remember maps aren't copied by value, so if we declared
    // the map m outside of the rows.Next() loop, we would be appending
    // and modifying the same map for each row, so all rows in list would look the same.
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i, val := range vals {
        m[cols[i]] = val
    }
    list = append(list, m)
}

// 3. Print.
b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(list, "", "\t")
fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
```

Don't worry, this was hard for me to understand when I was a beginner as well.

Now, something fun:

```
var list []map[string]interface{}
rows, err := db.Queryx(query)
for rows.Next() {
    row := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = rows.MapScan(row)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    list = append(list, row)
}

b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(list, "", "\t")
fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
```

This does the same as the code above it, but with [sqlx](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/). A bit simpler, no?

sqlx is an extension on top of `database/sql` with methods to scan rows directly to maps and structs, so you don't have to do that manually.

I think your model looks nicer as a struct:

```
type Person struct {
    ID int
    Name string
}

var people []Person
rows, err := db.Queryx(query)
for rows.Next() {
    var p Person
    err = rows.StructScan(&p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    people = append(people, p)
}
```

Don't you think?

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfect. I am aware of sqlx, but did not fix the base64 to string conversion. Numeric did not show up correct. And using structs are the last resort, as I often not know the structs.

Comment: It seem to be a problem though. This code could not handle NULL values. It crashes. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try replacing `vals[i] = &s` with `vals[i] = &&s`, but then it might only work with nullable columns, I'm not sure.

Comment: My bad, try without & at all, and change the line before to `var s **string`

Comment: @ moshe-revah Crashes on everything. Even not NULL

Comment: it seems that combination "var s **string + vals[i] = &s" did the trick. I will investigate more.

Comment: @sibert Makes sense, now that I'm not looking at it from my phone ;-) Good luck!