# How to convert pgx.Rows from Query() to json array?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm using `github.com/jackc/pgx` for work with postgreSQL.
Noq I want to convert pgx.Rows from Query() to json array.
I tried func for `*sql.Rows`, but it doesn't work for `*pgx.Rows`

```
func PgSqlRowsToJson(rows *pgx.Rows) []byte {
   fieldDescriptions := rows.FieldDescriptions()
   var columns []string
   for _, col := range fieldDescriptions {
    columns = append(columns, col.Name)
   }

   count := len(columns)
   tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
   values := make([]interface{}, count)
   valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
   for rows.Next() {
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
    }
    rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
    entry := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i, col := range columns {
        var v interface{}
        val := values[i]
        b, ok := val.([]byte)
        if ok {
            v = string(b)
        } else {
            v = val
        }
        entry[col] = v
    }
    tableData = append(tableData, entry)
   }
   jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(tableData)

   return jsonData
}
```

The problem is that `Scan()` doesn't work with `interface{}` and it works with explicitly defined types only.
Can you help me how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure as I'm not a user of pgx, but looking at the docs I think you can use https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#FieldDescription.Type with https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New and https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface to populate `valuePtrs`.

Comment: ... here's an untested example so I'm unsure if it will work or not: https://play.golang.org/p/q21zjeCaYh9

Comment: Maybe you can find some clues here (not pqx) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075134/how-to-append-last-sql-row-to-a-list-without-replacing-previous-rows-in-golang

Comment: @mkopriva, it works! Thanks a lot! Add an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`pgx.FieldDescription`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#FieldDescription)'s [`Type`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#FieldDescription.Type) method to retrieve a column's expected type. Passing that to [`reflect.New`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) you can then allocate a pointer to a value of that type, and with these newly allocated values you can then make a slice of non-nil `interface{}s` whose underlying values have the expected type.

For example:

```
func PgSqlRowsToJson(rows *pgx.Rows) []byte {
    fieldDescriptions := rows.FieldDescriptions()
    var columns []string
    for _, col := range fieldDescriptions {
        columns = append(columns, col.Name)
    }

    count := len(columns)
    tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)

    valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
    for rows.Next() {
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
            valuePtrs[i] = reflect.New(fieldDescriptions[i].Type()).Interface() // allocate pointer to type
        }
        rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)

        entry := make(map[string]interface{})
        for i, col := range columns {
            var v interface{}
            val := reflect.ValueOf(valuePtrs[i]).Elem().Interface() // dereference pointer
            b, ok := val.([]byte)
            if ok {
                v = string(b)
            } else {
                v = val
            }
            entry[col] = v
        }
        tableData = append(tableData, entry)
    }
    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(tableData)

    return jsonData
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for any extended types, like UUID or datetime?

Comment: @BZapper What types are you referring to? Do you mean this [UUID](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx/pgtype#UUID) type? And what about datetime? There does not seem to be such a type in the pgx package...

Comment: sorry, meant timestamptz and UUID. They seem to get ignored and return nil value per my test.

Comment: @BZapper I don't have pgx installed so I cannot debug this myself. You'll have to play around with it a bit to find the problem. If you haven't tried yet, start by looking at what the `fieldDescriptions[i].Type()` expression returns. I believe it should return a `reflect.Type` representation of `pgtype.UUID` and `pgtype.Timestamptz`, that is if the respecitve columns have those types of course... If it doesn't return that then the cause of your problem will be in pgx's source. If it does return that then the problem might be in the `range columns` loop...

Comment: Looking at the source of the `Type` method it does seem like it's not checking for UUID, so that could be the reasonn why that doesn't work as expected, however it does seem to check for Timestamptz so I'm not sure what's going on. But you can try to handle the two types yourself if you want by extending the above snippet by a few lines.

Comment: First you'll need to inspect the `fieldDescription` datatype to allocate the correct type for scanning, then, you need to choose the correct way how you want those types to be marshaled into json, this is because pgtype.UUID and pgtype.Timestamptz do not implement the json.Marshaler interface so you will have to decide for yourself how to marshal values of those type.

Comment: @BZapper here's an example https://play.golang.com/p/RbKe7DZWStq but keep in mind that I haven't tested the code, there may be logical errors there, so go through it carefully and if it compiles then just modify it to fit your solution. If this doesn't help then unfortunately I don't know what else could. I'm too lazy to install the package and debug it myself.

Comment: I cannot resolve this error "fieldDescriptions[i].Type undefined (type pgproto3.FieldDescription has no field or method Type)" version compatibility  issues ?

Comment: @AbhijitGujar if you want to use the above approach you'll have to switch to `pgx/v3` or lower. `pgx/v4` uses the new `pgproto3.FieldDescription` which does not have the `Type() reflect.Type` method anymore.